# Need to keep image (horizontal / vertical) in a fixed height div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am following my previous question that has two boxes, that have two images **(can be vertical or horizontal)**, the issue is the height of boxes are fixed and when I change the window screen in some screen sizes the images bypass the border of the boxes.

I checked answers of these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070632/vertically-aligning-images-in-a-fixed-height-div) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478440/vertical-align-image-in-a-fixed-height-block) but did not help much.

[image]

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/6y4uf16y/4/)

**CSS**

```
.items { */
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    padding-left: 1%;
    height:260px;

}



.col-md-12.col-xs-12.btn>a>img {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.col-md-12.col-xs-12.my-col {
    padding-left: 100%;
}

.my-row {
    bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.my-row {
    bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.btn {
    float: right;
    bottom:0;
    margin-right:-12px;
    margin-bottom:-6px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 items">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <h4>T1</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <h5>T2</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 row text-center">
                                <a
                                    href="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
                                    title="T1" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
                                    id="imageresource"
                                    src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
                                    class="img-thumbnail" width="30%" style="margin-left: 30px;" />
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" class="btn" /></a>
                                </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="col-md-3 items">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <h4>T1</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <h5>T2</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 row text-center">
                                <a
                                    href="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
                                    title="T1" data-gallery rel="nofollow"> <img
                                    id="imageresource"
                                    src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong"
                                    class="img-thumbnail" width="25%" style="margin-left: 30px;" />
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="#" class="btn" /></a>
                                </div>
                    </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: may b i am confused which boxes you are talking about.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara please click on 'Demo' to see the demo of the code. There are two red boxes.

Comment: I know of a class `img-responsive` which when added to any `<img>` makes it responsive and the image never go out of bounds. your code is making me confused and have made me :( because it contains a lot of junk which is not needed here. you try and add the class and state the result, your problem is solved or not?

Comment: @RohitKumar I added the class but did not help, which parts are junk?

Comment: the long values of hrefs and srcs, data- attributes, target attributes, etc, by the way, i checked your demo link and in that i found that the images are not going out of the borders of the divs, they are automatically resizing. what actually you want?

Comment: @RohitKumar I just included a screenshot that shows the issue. You can see that images do not have the same size and the one in the top box is overlapping the bottom border of its box.

Comment: okay i noticed it. so do you want your images height and width to become fixed when they tend to go out of boundary OR do you want to resize the div containing the image according to the image height?

Comment: I need them to be resized but keep the size of the boxes the same. The images should be resized in their boxes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First off**, the markup is over complicated for what you want and line 15 and 45 are applying bootstrap classes `.col-md-12` and `.row` on the same element which is in incorrect. Bootstrap class `.col-xx-nn` must be assigned to a child element with a bootstrap class `.row`.

**Getting back on track to what you want**. I have simplified the HTML code to get your desired result, I think. Check it out and let me know what isn't right and I will change it and explain why.

https://jsfiddle.net/6y4uf16y/84/

What I did was create a container `div` around the sale image that uses the CSS flex box. This div will take up any remaining space. Therefore, if you change the height of your `.items` element. The flexbox container will adapt and the sale image will respond appropriately to the new size. There is no fixed heights here except for the one that was placed on the `.items` class of `260px` which I believe is what you wanted.

The reason for this is that the bootstrap class .img-reponsive needs a height and/or width attribute to be responsive. Therefore, I have set the height and width equal to the flex box container around it. You can change the `width` value or `.img-sale` back to `30%` if you wish.

**Moreover, as a bonus**, I have aligned the button to always be in the bottom right corner as I think you wanted it.

If this answer solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as the correct solution.

Cheers

**Edit** Sorry wrong JSFiddle link, correct link has been added. I also added proof that it is dynamic with multiple rows of text in the h4 and h5 elements.

Comment: I followed this tutorial (section Basic Structure of a Bootstrap Grid) thats why I have .col-xx-nn in side .row class. Please let me know if I am missing something. thanks http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Having an element of `.col-xx-nn` as a **child** of an element `.row` is correct as w3schools.com shows in said tutorial [above](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp). However, what I am referring to is line 15 and line 45 of your JSFiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/6y4uf16y/4/), where you placed the CSS class `.col-md-12` and class `.row` together on the same element which is not allowed. I'm assuming this was an accident or typo if you said you followed the tutorial on w3schools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issues are I need to have different widths per image. Also the images at the right corner bottom overlaps middle images in small screens.

Comment: I see, those classes are combined 'row text-center' I used them to keep the images in the middle of the boxes.

Comment: You can simply apply css `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to center any block element within its parent's boundaries which means you don't need to add the Bootstrap classes `.row .text-center` to center an image.

Comment: In terms of different widths per image, could you elaborate on that a little more in terms of how that relates to image height relative to the red container?

Comment: I need to have images with different widths lets say first one might be 30% and the other 45% however, I need them all to stay in their boxes.

Comment: Right now I have added it so the image scales to fill either the maximum available height or the maximum available width depending which boundary the image hits first. I have done this with the CSS properties `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`. This tells the browser to not let the image extend past the bounder of its parent's container. You can modify these values how you see fit. If you don't know about this already, you can also combine the max properties with `min-height` or `min-width` as well the normal `height` and `width` values to achieve the desired behavior you are looking for

Comment: Great, please have a look at my other question as well thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509918/how-to-design-a-row-of-images

Answer (score 1):

You have to add class

```
.col-md-12 >a>img.btn {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

because **.col-md-12.col-xs-12.btn>a>img**  is not applying to any of your given HTML div content

Answer (score 1):

Is it a design requirement that the images get wider as the boxes get wider? If so, the only way to keep the images within the boxes is to increase the height of the boxes as you increase the height of the images.

If it's not a requirement that the images scale up, then you can see my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4uf16y/75/

All I did was remove the explicit widths from your images (the first was `width="25%"` and the second was `width="30%"`) and instead used CSS to control the scale by limiting the max-height of the images. `.items img {max-height:100px;}`.

*Since you have a fixed height and need to keep the images inside the boxes, you know for a fact that also have a fixed maximum height on the images*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to show images in different sizes thats why I have a width attribute per image. The requirement is to keep the images at the middle of their boxes, by changing screen size the box sizes should change therefore the image sizes should change proportionally.

Comment: You can keep the images in the middle of the boxes without scaling them up (which is what happens with the % width). When you think about it, there's also just no way to increase the width on an image without increasing the height (at least not without either cropping the image or stretching it). The nice thing about that max-height attribute is that you know regardless of what your image aspect ratio is, it'll never overflow your container. If set a max-width too, you'd be covered you for all images.

Comment: I added a couple of CSS rules to overwrite the default styles for `.text-center` and to demonstrate different ARs for images that will stay in the container: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4uf16y/76/ . For the sake of making the code a little more readable I added consolidated your border-radius `border-radius: 20px 20px 0 20px;` & I combined your margin rules on `.items` to make the positioning more obvious. I also updated my styles at the bottom: `.items .row.text-center {text-align:center;padding:0;} .items .row {margin:0;} .items img {max-height:160px; max-width:100%; display:block; margin:auto;}`

Comment: By the way! Once you apply absolute or fixed positioning, things like 'float' don't matter anymore (I could be wrong, but I think that's true 100% of the time). Also if you're specifying absolute positioning, you can simplify your `.btn` class by getting rid of the negative margins and using the positioning rules instead (ex: `.btn {bottom:-6px; right:-12px; position:absolute;}` if you actually need the negative positioning. I think with how I changed your styles, though, `bottom:0; right:0;` should get you what you're looking for.)

Comment: In Firefox, the images stay the exact same size all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can have line break on T1 & T2, otherwise you can do this

```
img{
    max-height:170px;
    width:auto
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6y4uf16y/80/)

Comment: In Firefox, the images stay the exact same size all the time.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @Bhavin Solanki and may be the one thing i will suggest that try to give the

```css
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
```

in to percentages Or else you can go with Media queries for the particular image selectors that will help you to manage a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Bootstrap code isn't totally correct:

1. You can't nest a `.col-md-12` class inside a `.col-md-3` class not
   in my knowledge at least.
2. Your `.rows` classes are not always well positioned within the code
   see the **fiddle** link that i prepared below.

I tried to do my best to understand what you want to achieve with your code i also ordered tags within your code so that your divs fit the window size regardless of its width.

**EDIT**

Try to define the width of your image with vw unit (`width:15vw;`) That will keep the image from crossing the containing item.

I illustrated an example for you here :

http://jsfiddle.net/merhzqwg/65/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to have two boxes next to each other, each has two texts on its first two lines followed by an image in the middle and another at the most bottom right corner of each box. The issue with my current design is that if you change the size of screen you would see the images pass the border of the red boxes that they are located in. I would like to make sure they won't override the border of the box they are located in, in any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is the thing, your code is not very clean. there are some errors as well

for eg: you have used the `id="imageresource"` twice. An `id` can **ONLY** be used once on a single page. **Very Important**.

but i will provide a quick fix for this.

by default bootstrap adds   `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` to the class `img-thumbnail` to override that what i have done is i have added a class to both of the images `img-sale`.

```
<img class="img-thumbnail img-sale" id="imageresource" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKWYNnGt8d9G1sf8PE0TpOglpZ2dKnHWAP5FB_spYgelcToong" width="30%" style="margin-left: 30px;" />
```

and added the following css:

```
.img-sale {
  max-height: 170px;
  width: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVwrpJ?editors=110

http://jsfiddle.net/6y4uf16y/82/

but the rest of the code is not recommended to proceed with.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you advice which other parts need to be changed?