# How to design a row of images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to change my design to have 7 boxes in a single row. Each box would have an image and a caption underneath of it. I need to have specific left and right margins, similar to following:

```
       My images
       img1  img2  img3  img4  img5  img6  img7 
        c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7
```

**Code**

```
  <h3>My Images</h3>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C1</p>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <p>C7</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you changed the default grid value from 12 columns to something else? If no, then the above will not give you the desired result

Comment: @nikhil how to do that?

Comment: John has an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `col-xs-3` will only allow you to have 4 columns in a row (since a grid has only 12 columns).

Since you need each column on a separate row on *extra small* screens (mobile screens or `xs` screens), use `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-1`. This would mean that each div occupies `12` columns on an `xs` screen and `1` column on `sm` screens and above.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <p>C1</p>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p>C1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p>C2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p>C3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p>C4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      <p>C5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did but the issue is in mobile screen sizes the images will be shown in a row. I need each to be in a sparate row in mobile screen sizes.

Comment: @DanielNewtown Check the updated answer. You can read more about Bootstrap's grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: oo I missed that, alright thanks. The only issue is as illustrated in the example I need to have a specific margin-left and margin-right for the row in big screens. How can I enforce that? I can use 'container' class to wrap them but I would not be able to have col-sm-1 because the images would be to small. If I use col-sm-2 also the overall columns  would be more than 12 so the last one would not stay on the same row.

Comment: You can add an [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to the first `div` - `<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1">`, which will basically leave 1 column's space on md screens before the div.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you really want a design with seven columns. Luckily, Bootstrap is highly customizable and they have a [handy UI for creating your own build](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system). Once you have a seven-column grid (or let's say you make it easy on yourself, come up with 1 more image, and compromise with an 8-column grid) then use `col-xs-8 col-sm-1`, which will make the images 8 columns wide (basically full-width) on extra small screens, and 1 column wide (about 1/8 width) on small screens.

Comment: I am confused. would you give me an example?

Comment: I should have asked for more context. Are you working on an already-existing site that uses a 12-column Bootstrap grid? Do you absolutely need to have *7* images?

Comment: Yes I am working on a 12-column bootstrap grid and I need to have only 7 images.